# how to delete all remote branches after pull request

Tags: git, bash, github

I want  to delete all remote branches where pull request has been completed. I have done following

```
git branch --merged | grep  "feature/" | xargs -n 1 echo "origin/" | sed 's/ //g' git branch -d -r
```

but this throws an error.

Comment: What error does it throw? Also, `|` missing before the last `git`?

Comment: Same as @choroba, + `xargs git ...`

Comment: sed: unknown option --d

Comment: when i add | before last git it says branch name required

Comment: @choroba + @LeGEC = change final `sed 's/ //g' git` to `sed 's/ //g' | xargs git`

Comment: thanks webb that solved it